# How do I disable Entry in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```py
def com():
    ...
    entryy=Entry()
    entryy.pack()
    
    button=Button(text="Enter!", command=com, font=(24))
    button.pack(expand="yes", anchor="center")
```

As I said how do I disable Entry in `com` function?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Set `state` to `'disabled'`.

For example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
entry = Entry(root, state='disabled')
entry.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

or

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
entry = Entry(root)
entry.config(state='disabled') # OR entry['state'] = 'disabled'
entry.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

See [`Tkinter.Entry.config`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.config-method)

---

So the `com` function should read as:

```
def com():
    entry.config(state='disabled')
```

Comment: Well,I understand now

Comment: @EmekKırarslan, I added `com` function. Check it out.

Comment: Well,How I can completely remove and restore

Comment: @EmekKırarslan, What do you mean by **remove**? Does **restore** mean back to normal state? Then, use `entry.config(state='normal')`

Comment: I mean delete, eliminate

Comment: @EmekKırarslan, I don't understand. Do you want delete the content of the entry? Then, use `entry.delete(0, 'end')`.

Comment: @EmekKırarslan, I see, use `entry.pack_forget()`. See [Tkinter.Pack.pack_forget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack_forget-method).

Comment: @EmekKırarslan, `entry.pack()` again! Please post another separated question if you have any other question, instead of extending comments.

Answer (score 3):

if we want to change again and again data in entry box we will have to first convert into Normal state after changing data we will convert in to disable state

```
import tkinter as tk
count = 0

def func(en):
    en.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
    global count
    count += 1
    count=str(count)
    en.delete(0, tk.END)
    text = str(count)
    en.insert(0, text)
    en.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
    count=int(count)


root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text='Click', command=lambda: func(e))
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```